# can we use array-selector to select / deselect all in polymer

Tags: polymer

It seems array-selector can be used only for selecting / deslecting individual items. Can we do a select all / deselect all in single shot ? It would be great if have that feature. Thanks !

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates

Answer (score 0):

You can set `multi` as true to select multiple items

> When multi is false, selected is a property representing the last selected item. When multi is true, selected is an array of selected items.

[Here's](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/array-selector) the reference API for `array-selector`

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking for a way to select all items in the master array in array-selector. Understand that we have the capability to select multiple items by enabling the multi property. As of now, we have to iterate each array item and need to explicitly add them to the array-selector. Let me know if my question is not clear. Thanks !

Comment: What exactly is the question? and what do you mean by explicitly adding them?

Comment: He means is there a function that selects or deselects every item in the array in one call instead of manually selecting or deselecting every individual entry  one by one.

Comment: I can't find any such function in the documentation or code of array-selector. You can try and raise it as feature request in github.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there [isn't currently any progress being mad](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/3827)e on a select/deselect all function for array-selector.

In the interim, here's some quick and dirty code that will get the job done.

```
// deselect all
selected = this.$.{{array-selector-element-id}}.selected.slice(0);
for (i = 0, len = selected.length; i < len; i++) {
  item = selected[i];
  this.$.selector.deselect(item);
}

// select all
items = this.$.{{array-selector-element-id}}.items;
for (i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
  item = item[i];
  this.$.selector.select(item);
}
```

Probably wouldn't be too hard to do a pull request on this.